# NextJS API "pages/api/contactUs.js" not working on Vercel production, but working fine on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have seen many similar questions on StackOverflow but none of them has provided a valid solution.

My code structure is this

```
pages/api/contactUs.js
```

my code is

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'Next.js' })
}
```

API is working on my local but on Vercel production, it gave status code 404

Please help me to resolve this issue for production.

Comment: Similar code is working in my app after vercel deployment. Did you check if it is a casing issue ? can you try with same case as the filename

Comment: How are you posting to that API endpoint?

Comment: Could you share your code or repository? That should work fine. You might consider using hypen-case for the file name, so contact-us, so your route is yoursite.com/api/contact-us.